# ¿Cómo añado un estilo diferente a cada columna de una tabla que imprimo desde un array?

Tags: php, html, html5, array, foreach

Estoy imprimiendo los valores de un array en una tabla con PHP y lo que quiero es aplicar un estilo diferente solo a las columnas con los valores de "TOTAL" y "PRECIO", pero no sé cómo debería hacerlo, intente con `$v['total']` pero es incorrecto, ¿Como debería hacerlo?

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="color:#555;font-size: 13px;" class="text-center">ID PRODUCTO</th>
      <th style="color:#555;font-size: 13px;" class="text-center">MEDICAMENTO</th>
      <th style="color:#555;font-size: 13px;" class="text-center">PRECIO</th>
      <th style="color:#555;font-size: 13px;" class="text-center">PRESENTACION</th>
      <th style="color:#555;font-size: 13px;" class="text-center">COMPONENTES</th>
      <th style="color:#555;font-size: 13px;" class="text-center">LABORATORIO</th>
      <th style="color:#555;font-size: 13px;" class="text-center">CANTIDAD</th>
      <th style="color:#555;font-size: 13px;" class="text-center">TOTAL</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<?php
    foreach ($carrito as $r) {
        echo '<tr>';
        foreach ($r as $v) {
            echo  '<td class="text-center">'.$v.'</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    ?>
</table>
```

El array lo lleno asi:

```
array("id_producto" => $producto, "medicamento" => $descripcion,"precio" => $precio,"presentacion" => $presentacion,"componentes" => $componentes,"laboratorio" => $laboratorio, "cantidad" => $cantidad, "total" => $total);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías usar [`colgroup`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/colgroup)

#### Ejemplo:

```css
.precio {
    background-color: #d7d9f2;
}

.cantidad {
    background-color: #ffe8d4;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-bordered">
  <colgroup>
    <col span="2">
    <col class="precio">
    <col span="3">
    <col class="cantidad">
  </colgroup>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="color:#555;font-size: 13px;" class="text-center">ID PRODUCTO</th>
      <th style="color:#555;font-size: 13px;" class="text-center">MEDICAMENTO</th>
      <th style="color:#555;font-size: 13px;" class="text-center">PRECIO</th>
      <th style="color:#555;font-size: 13px;" class="text-center">PRESENTACION</th>
      <th style="color:#555;font-size: 13px;" class="text-center">COMPONENTES</th>
      <th style="color:#555;font-size: 13px;" class="text-center">LABORATORIO</th>
      <th style="color:#555;font-size: 13px;" class="text-center">CANTIDAD</th>
      <th style="color:#555;font-size: 13px;" class="text-center">TOTAL</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-center">ID PRODUCTO</td>
      <td class="text-center">MEDICAMENTO</td>
      <td class="text-center">PRECIO</td>
      <td class="text-center">PRESENTACION</td>
      <td class="text-center">COMPONENTES</td>
      <td class="text-center">LABORATORIO</td>
      <td class="text-center">CANTIDAD</td>
      <td class="text-center">TOTAL</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono.

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer de esta manera

```
<?php
    foreach ($carrito as $r) {
        $estilos = "style='TUS ESTILOS BASE'";
        if($r["total"] && $r["precio"]){//Validas si existe el total
           $estilos = "style='TUS NUEVOS ESTILOS'";
        }
        echo '<tr '.$estilos.'>';
        foreach ($r as $v) {
            echo  '<td class="text-center">'.$v.'</td>';
            }
            echo '</tr>';
        }
    ?>
?>
```

Nada mas inicias una variable con los estilos base o incluso la puedes dejar como `$estilos="";` de esta manera no imprime nada, sin embargo cuando se cumpla la condicion entonces se aplican nuevos estilos, la ventaja de esto es que se puede aplicar por fila.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, la probé y tambien me funciono. Saludos.